# HDF5 Viewer does not show all groups at root level

Tags: hdf5

We are using 3rd party software to generate an HDF5 file.  The file has many groups at the root level, but the HDF5 viewer does not show them all.  It shows the first 7600+ groups, but not the last groups.

These groups do exist, because I've written some very simple software that reads the file and displays what groups are there.

Are there any known limitations in terms of what the HDF5 viewer can show from an HDF5 file?

Answer (score 0):

The limitation was set to avoid OutOfMemoryError from JVM. You can reset the limitation at Tools->Max Members. For example, set it to 20,000. the default is 10,000.